# Using a JDialog as input

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I am trying to use a `JDialog` as input for a `String`. But the text I get is from before I click the Button.

this is my dialog:

```
public class AddMemberDialog extends JDialog {

    private JTextField name;

    public AddMemberDialog() {
        super(new JFrame("Add Member"), "Add Member");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        this.name = new JTextField();

        JButton add = new JButton("Add");
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                close();            
            }
        });
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));

        this.add(name);
        this.add(add);
        this.pack();
    }

    private void close(){   this.dispose(); }

    public String getName(){    return this.name.getText(); }
}
```

and here is what I am using to get to `String`:

```
AddMemberDialog input = new AddMemberDialog();
input.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
input.setVisible(true);
String txt = input.getName();
```

Comment: You need to make an ActionListener for your button and then only take the code after the button has been pressed. I had a similar issue with my code [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198989/how-to-wait-for-user-input-when-using-jtextfields)

Comment: Or rather, make another button that handles that, as I see this button is for closing

Comment: in your constructor, add "setModal(true);"

Comment: But what I mean is this `String txt = input.getName();` gets the value as the Dialog opens and I wanted to get it as it closes

Comment: Right because it is doing it automatically, literally the second it opens, it takes in input. I am saying, don't take in the input until a button or something has been pressed, otherwise, you won't be able to do anything about getting the input

Comment: Would you like me to post a code example?

Comment: @ControlAltDel used your hit and it worked thanks

Comment: @DreadHeadedDeveloper if you don't mind I'd like it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.GridLayout;


public class AddMemberDialog extends JDialog 
{

   private JTextField name;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      AddMemberDialog input = new AddMemberDialog();
      input.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      input.setVisible(true);

   }

   public AddMemberDialog() 
   {
      super(new JFrame("Add Member"), "Add Member");

      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
      this.name = new JTextField();

      JButton add = new JButton("Add");
      add.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {

               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                  close();            
               }
            });



      JButton takeInput = new JButton("takeInput");
      takeInput.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener()
            {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
               {


                  String txt = getName();
                  System.out.println(txt);

               }
            }
            );

      this.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));

      this.add(name);
      this.add(add);
      this.add(takeInput);
      this.pack();
   }

   private void close()
   {   

      this.dispose(); 

   }

   public String getName()
   {    

      return this.name.getText(); 

   }

}
```

Alright, so basically, your issue here is that, if you simply leave the code

```
              AddMemberDialog input = new AddMemberDialog();
              input.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
              input.setVisible(true);
              String txt = input.getName();
```

It will automatically take in your input the second the IDE reaches that line of code. Namely, unless you put something into it before the IDE gets there (and the IDE gets there in milliseconds), it won't take anymore input after that. So to compensate, we don't let the program take input until we are good and ready, hence the need for a button. In my above code, I made a new `JButton` and called it `takeInput`. Also gave it an `ActionListener` and in that `ActionListener`, made it do what you asked for. Now, I can control when the input happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOptionPane for this.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestClass
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Add Member");
    System.out.println(input);
  }
}
```